# Can't cast a function inside an object to a type

Tags: typescript

I try to cast a function inside an object to a type.

Why does this not work?

```js
export type Validator<TInput> = (
  input: TInput
) => Promise<{ [key: string]: string }>;

const works: Validator<string> = async (input) => {
  return {};
};

const doesNotWork = {
  myFancyProperty: Validator<string> = async (input) => {
    return {};
  }
}

=> 'Validator' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

What's the correct syntax?
I've searched and tried for an hour now.
Maybe i am to tired.

Comment: Because that's the wrong syntax for object declaration. You should type objects, not object properties.

Comment: Thats right! I go to bed now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify a property type in that way.

Your best bet is to type the object, rather than the property:

```typescript
const works1: {myFancyProperty: Validator<string>} = {
    myFancyProperty: async (input) => {
        return {};
    },
};
```

But in **rare cases**, you might use a type assertion on the value you're assigning:

```typescript
const works2 = {
    myFancyProperty: (async (input) => {
        return {};
    }) as Validator<string>,
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBM7APYCcA8AVASQDswBXYAPigF4oAKAKCmaiRPIC4pD3gGBKGlQAKWDAFskAZwg4A3lADaAawgguU4FjYBzALoatuqAF8KAbgYMAxhiKaoAd2zKpARi5zxIAGJwi1iCiGJBYoFzwyGiYuJraRDoUJjRQckws3n4BQWKh4VBwUiAB9GxkwILUVGkstVBYEMCkWESpJpa1JgA0DO1WtvbATi5SAEwpNRm+-oHBeer0hcXWpbyV1el19Y3NrXJ9nYKFsIio6Ng4cboUPX1AA)